# Visual Studio - Ionic: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a project of Ionic on Visual Studio 2015 and I get the next error

[Error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC8Rx.png)

This happened after I tried using $cordovaActionSheet in my project

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on a project of Ionic on Visual Studio 2015 and I get the next error
>   Error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Please check if you have installed the `Android Support Repository`.

1. Find the android SDK Manager(By default it's under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`).
2. Run `SDK Manager.exe` as administrator.
3. Find `Android Support Respository` under `Extra\Android Support Respository` and install it:

[image]

For details about this support library please refer to [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#choosing).

Comment: The error comes out from `BackgroundActionButtonHandler.java`, which is part of [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). The `android.support.v4` is missing. If you have already installed Android Support Respository, then your app maybe not referenced it correctly. Could you please try removing the android platform with CLI and build it again? If the error persists, could you maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Thanks, I guess the plugin didn't installed correctly
Now is fixed

Comment: I have the same problem